# error CNDL0005 : The Product element contains an unexpected child element 'Dialog'

Tags: msbuild, wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

I am trying to make an MSI installer using the instructions available at https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/a-single-dialog/.

I tried putting the Dialog tag inside the Product tag/ Wix tag, but in both those locations got the below error:

`error CNDL0005 : The Product element contains an unexpected child element 'Dialog'.`

Please help me resolve this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Dialog` tag should not be nested within a `Product` tag, but should instead be placed within a `UI` tag, as described in the [WiX schema documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/ui.html).

Comment: Yes, the help topic for each element has a list of allowed parents: [Dialog]( http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/dialog.html).